# How to switch through pages using Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intel-xdk

This is my first question, so I hope everything is fine

Here is an easy example HTML using intelXDK App-designer

```
<div class="uwrap" id="content">
     <div class="upage vertical-col left panel" id="mainpage" data-header="af-header-1" data-footer="af-footer-4">
         <a class="button widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="switch">Button</a>
     </div>
     <div class="upage vertical-col left panel" id="timepage" data-header="af-header-2" data-footer="af-footer-5">
         <a class="button widget uib_w_7 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="back">Button</a>
     </div>
</div>
<footer class="wrap-element uib_w_6" data-uib="app_framework/footer" data-ver="1" id="af-footer-5">
    <a class="widget uib_w_8 d-margins icon check" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1">Button</a>
</footer>
<footer class="wrap-element uib_w_2" data-uib="app_framework/footer" data-ver="1" id="af-footer-4">
    <a class="widget uib_w_3 d-margins icon home" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1">Button</a>
    <a class="widget uib_w_5 d-margins icon tv" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1">Button</a>
</footer>
```

How can I switch between pages? ('mainpage', 'timepage')

```
$(document).on("click", "#switch", function(evt)
{
     activate_page("#timepage"); 
});
```

This automatically generated jQuery code doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I was looking for is shown below:

```
$(document).on("click", "#back", function(evt)
{
     //activate_page("#mainpage"); 
     af.ui.loadContent("#mainpage",false,false,"fade");
});
```

Comment: This applies to 'App Framework' projects, right? (instead of jQuery projects, where the 'activate_page()' should be correct)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#switch", function(evt)
{
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#timepage").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/8tLdq/1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you import jQuery file? id selector is not working in app_framwork.
2. You have to set href attribute in your `<a>`